# Karma e2e testing: how to know when the DOM is ready?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I'm writing some e2e tests and up until now I have been using the `sleep(x)` function to wait for ajax calls.

This is not very efficient as I must estimate the value to wait for testing and if I set too big a value then my tests are taking much more time then needed.

Is there a way to sleep for an ajax call duration? or at least when redirecting to a different page a way to sleep for the time the DOM is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do e2e testing with angular scenario runner and karma you do not need to worry about this. The framework handels all this for you. If you have a button that will cause your application to send an AJAX request and on response change something in the DOM, you can simply write your test like this:

```
element('#mybutton').click();
expect('...'); //Test that checks that the DOM has changed as excpected.
```

As long as you use angular full out, this will work.

Comment: wow that's unexpected, I had to add those sleep in the past to have e2e tests pass. I'll double check. And yes I'm using solely angular. Thanks

Comment: so it appears I was using direct `document.location.href` change which is not handled by karma. For the rest it works out of the box.